# Why is .NET Core constantly redirecting on Mac?

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying to set up a .NET Core project on Mac; it works fine on Windows but I can't get it running on Mac.

Everything builds up correctly after `dotnet run`, displaying this message in Terminal:

```
[09:46:04 INF] Now listening on: http://localhost:44382
```

However, when I enter this address, it just returns me 302 and redirects me to `https://localhost/`. And of course, nothing exists there.

This is my `launchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost/OW.WebApplication.Web",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44365/",
      "sslPort": 44365
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44365/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "OW_LOCAL_DEV": "true",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "development",
        "OW_KEYVAULT": "https://ffffff-development.vault.azure.net/",
        "OW_E2E_TEST_TOKEN": "BcAdl0ffffffffff3LOERQ69Y"
      }
    },
    "OW.WebApplication.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "OW_LOCAL_DEV": "true",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "development",
        "OW_KEYVAULT": "https://ffffff-development.vault.azure.net/"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44382/"
    }
  }
}
```

I guess there's something wrong with this config but I just can't figure it out. Any tips would help a lot.

**EDIT:**
Here's my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>

        <!--<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="GeoServer" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^geoserver(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://geoserver.azurewebsites.net/geoserver{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>-->
    </system.webServer>
    <system.net>
        <settings>
            <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false" checkCertificateRevocationList="false" />
        </settings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

And log:

```
2021-01-05 14:51:55.522 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44382/  
2021-01-05 14:51:55.525 +00:00 [DBG] Wildcard detected, all requests with hosts will be allowed.
2021-01-05 14:51:55.571 +00:00 [DBG] The request path / does not match an existing file
2021-01-05 14:51:55.591 +00:00 [DBG] AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
2021-01-05 14:51:55.592 +00:00 [INF] Request redirected to HTTPS
2021-01-05 14:51:55.593 +00:00 [DBG] Request is done processing. Location header 'https://localhost/' with status code '302'.
2021-01-05 14:51:55.595 +00:00 [INF] HTTP GET / responded 302 in 65.4414 ms
```

I've updated my Startup.cs file with this code:

```
services
    .AddHttpsRedirection(options => {
        options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
        options.HttpsPort = 44365;
    });
```

And now I can't even start the app.

Comment: When you run on Windows is it using IIS Express?

Comment: @Dai yes, as far as I know, you can't use IIS Express on Mac.

Comment: What happens if you change your project to use the `OW.WebApplication.Web` profile instead of using IIS Express on Windows? Do you have a `web.config` and/or any IIS URL Rewrite rules in-effect?

Comment: @Dai the same thing happens on Windows using the `OW.WebApplication.Web` profile. I have `web.config`, I've updated the question so check it out. I've also added log, it might be helpful.

Comment: Hey @Dai, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have enabled the middleware to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in your `Startup.cs` file. Check whether you are using the `UseHttpsRedirection` middleware like so:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

You are also probably starting the application using `OW.WebApplication.Web` (Kestrel) instead of IIS Express. IIS Express has the ability to work with HTTPS while Kestrel requires a certificate to be setup otherwise you'll get a browser security warning. Note that **IIS Express does not work on Mac**, so that's why you're probably using Kestrel instead. This is what the drop down looks like on Visual Studio on Windows:

[image]

If redirection from HTTP to HTTPS is something that you need. Take a look at this [Port configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#port-configuration) doc to see how you can configure the HTTPS port for when you want to run the application in development where you will not be using the standard port 80 and 443.

Comment: @Muhamamad Rehan Saeed thanks for your help. There is app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in the code. I've updated my question with an updated Startup.cs file; now I can't event run the application. How should I configure ports rather than that? Also, should I do something else besides that?